# Magento Paypal & CCAvenue Integration

Tags: magento, paypal, ccavenue

In my magento when I have USD as Base currency, paypal works fine but for 500 Rs. product CCavenue just as For Rs 10 payment(I think Its taking USD Amt. 500Rs=10USD).

I also tried Base Currency as INR, In this case CCAvenue work fine but Paypal shows currency not supported error.

The Main thing is, I want Paypal & CCavnue both... Hope some one helps me out...

Comment: I'm sorry Hiren but I don't quite understand. You're wanting to use PayPal and another processor; that shouldn't be a problem. It sounds like you have different currencies set for PayPal vs CCavenue and neither one is processing it correctly. You should ask your question on the Magento forums or contact their customer support if you're not using the community edition.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar situation.

As paypal payments are not supported for India, setting the currency to INR would disable the paypal payment method! And you're right, it is taking the price in USD.

What you need to do is to add the product price in USD only, keep the base currency to USD but display currency to INR. That way, the website will display prices in INR only and both payment methods would work

Cheers!

Comment: Perfect answer for this

Answer (score 0):

This wont work as base currency if USD CC Avenue will not work and if Base Currency is INR PayPal will show error. If Base currency can be changed for each store view / language ( higher plans ) then it would work .

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/tweak_paypal_standard_for_non-supported_base_currency

You can enable paypal for INR :)